# Skype on Ubuntu 22.04: STARTUP_TIMEOUT_ERROR

Tags: skype

I just got a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I'm trying to install Skype (via snap, v8.89.0.403), but I get:

[image]

The button "Sign out" does nothing. The menu entries are not working.
Here is the log:

```
$ skype
+ [ -f /home/cdupont/snap/skype/common/.config/skypeforlinux/settings.json ]
+ export SKYPE_LOGS=/home/cdupont/snap/skype/233/logs
+ [ ! -d /home/cdupont/snap/skype/233/logs ]
+ exec /snap/skype/233/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
[1031/114323.787403:ERROR:aria_reporter.cc(105)] expecting aria url scheme

(skypeforlinux:3875): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:43:24.282: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1422:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(skypeforlinux:3875): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:43:24.286: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3308:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(skypeforlinux:3875): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:43:24.288: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3770:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
WARNING: Kernel has no file descriptor comparison support: Operation not permitted
[3875:1031/114325.663468:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Inhibit: object_path= /org/freedesktop/login1: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.103" (uid=1000 pid=3875 comm="/snap/skype/233/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforli" label="snap.skype.skype (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="Inhibit" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=802 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")
[3875:1031/114325.666119:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Inhibit: object_path= /org/freedesktop/login1: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.103" (uid=1000 pid=3875 comm="/snap/skype/233/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforli" label="snap.skype.skype (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="Inhibit" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.login1" (uid=0 pid=802 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-logind " label="unconfined")
[3875:1031/114330.330009:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[3875:1031/114330.331016:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.130" (uid=1000 pid=3875 comm="/snap/skype/233/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforli" label="snap.skype.skype (enforce)") interface="org.gnome.ScreenSaver" member="GetActive" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.gnome.ScreenSaver" (uid=1000 pid=1953 comm="/usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Scre" label="unconfined")
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at /snap/skype/233/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:503785
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:563
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at /snap/skype/233/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:503785
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:563
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at /snap/skype/233/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:503785
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:563
Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at /snap/skype/233/usr/share/skypeforlinux/resources/app.asar/main.js:2:503785
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:563

Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
```

Is it a networking problem? Or an AppArmor problem?
Thanks